# What's the different between cheap coolant and expensive ones?

Tags: motorcycle, coolant

I'm living mostly on hotter climate (20-35 Celsius).

Does expensive coolant make my engine running cooler? Or perhaps it will last longer than the cheaper one?

Comment: What do you consider cheap or expensive coolant? If you're comparing sales gimmicks of 50% water/50% antifreeze as 'premix' to 100% antifreeze, you're throwing away money on the 50/50 premix compared to one gallon of 100% antifreeze. You dilute the 100% antifreeze by making two gallons of 50/50 mix instead of buying two gallons of 50/50 premix. Guess who saves money? If you are comparing brand name to no name brand, compare the two ingredients; you save if you buy no name brands of equal formula.

Comment: @FDryer - It depends on how you look at 50/50 coolant. If you consider the cost of distilled water to cut the full strength coolant to 50/50, that's part of the cost. Also, 50/50 coolant ensures you're getting the right mixture into your engine. What if you only need one gallon or less of coolant? You buy the 100%, cut it with distilled water and have two, then you are leaving one on the shelf. There are plenty of reasons *not* to buy 100% which make economical sense.  Yes, overall it is more expensive if you compare the amount of what you're getting, but sometimes it just makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

The main difference between cheap and expensive car engine coolant is the quality of the ingredients used and the level of protection it provides.

Cheap coolants may use lower quality materials, such as ethylene glycol instead of propylene glycol, which is more expensive but less toxic. Cheap coolants may also contain fewer corrosion inhibitors, which can lead to premature wear and tear on the engine cooling system.

Expensive coolants, on the other hand, are typically made with higher quality ingredients and contain more corrosion inhibitors. This provides better protection for the engine cooling system and can help to extend the life of the engine.

*It is important to note that not all expensive coolants are created equal. It is important to choose a coolant that is specifically designed for your vehicle's engine and cooling system. You can find this information in your vehicle's owner's manual.*

**Which coolant should you choose?**

If you are on a budget, a cheap coolant may be an option for you. However, it is important to weigh the cost savings against the increased risk of engine damage. If you can afford it, it is generally best to choose a more expensive coolant that provides better protection for your engine.

Here are some additional things to consider when choosing a car engine coolant:

- **Compatibility**: Make sure to choose a coolant that is specifically
  designed for your vehicle's engine and cooling system. You can find
  this information in your vehicle's owner's manual.
- **Climate**: If you live in a cold climate, you will need to choose a
  coolant that has a lower freezing point.
- **Engine type**: Different types of engines require    different types
  of coolant. For example, diesel engines require a    different
  type of coolant than gasoline engines.
- **Performance**: If you have a high-performance vehicle, you    may want
  to choose a coolant that is specifically designed for high-performance engines. If you are unsure which coolant to choose, it is always best to consult with a qualified mechanic.